# Turn grid into a checkerboard pattern in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have successfully created a grid, but am now trying to turn my grid into a checkerboard pattern, preferably using a variant of the floodfill command. 
 how do I make sure the program recognizes which squares are even and which are odd? 
 
currently the IDE is set so `m[i][j]= 1` gives blue, while `m[i][j]= 0` gives red, which I am happy to keep, and so I do not need to define the colors. Thank you.

Code I have so far :

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
from math import *

m=zeros((100,100))
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        if (math.floor(i) % 10) != 0:
            if (math.floor(j) % 10) != 0:
                m[i][j]= 1
            else:
                m[i][j]= 0

imshow(m)
show()
```

Code output :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
def make_checkerboard(n_rows, n_columns, square_size):

    n_rows_, n_columns_ = int(n_rows/square_size + 1), int(n_columns/square_size + 1)
    rows_grid, columns_grid = np.meshgrid(range(n_rows_), range(n_columns_), indexing='ij')
    high_res_checkerboard = np.mod(rows_grid, 2) + np.mod(columns_grid, 2) == 1
    square = np.ones((square_size,square_size))
    checkerboard = np.kron(high_res_checkerboard, square)[:n_rows,:n_columns]

    return checkerboard


square_size = 5
n_rows = 14
n_columns = 67
checkerboard = make_checkerboard(n_rows, n_columns, square_size)
```

[image: generated checkerboard]

Answer (score 1):

You can check the sum of the two indices (row and column) and color it with the first color if it's odd and second otherwise. Something like:

```
for i in range(nrows):
    for j in range(ncols):
        m[i][j] = 0 if (i+j)%2 else 1
```

Comment: Beautifully simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulus operation:

```
m[i][j] = (i+j) % 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a linear array, fill every second value and reshape. 
In your case (even amount of columns), prepend one column and get rid of it after reshaping:

```
import numpy as np

rows = 100
cols = 100 + 1  # product of rows*cols must be odd, we fix it later
m = np.zeros((rows*cols, 1))  # create array
m[::2] = 1  # fill every second
m = np.reshape(m, (rows, cols))  # reshape array to matrix
m = m[:, :-1]  # cut additional column
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a checkerboard style array with NumPy, then resize it with [`scipy's imresize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html) to make that equal to your desired canvas area.

Thus, the steps would be :

1) Create a NumPy array of shape `(10,10)` corresponding to `10 x 10` sized checkerboard pattern. To do so, start with `zeros` array and fill the alternate rows and columns with `ones`  :

```
arr = np.zeros((10,10),dtype=int)
arr[::2,::2] = 1
arr[1::2,1::2] = 1
```

2) Resize the array `10x` to have `(100,100)` pixel sized output image :

```
from scipy.misc import imresize # Importing required function

out = imresize(arr,10*np.array(arr.shape),interp='nearest')/255
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With only minimal modification of your code it would look something like this:

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
from math import *

m=zeros((100,100))
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        if (math.floor(i) % 10) != 0:
            if (math.floor(j) % 10) != 0:
                m[i][j]= 1
        if (int(i / 10) + int(j / 10)) % 2:  # the only two extra lines. 
            m[i][j] = 0                      #
imshow(m)
show()
```

Alternatively just this (assuming you really need the 100x100) to get rid of the "boundary lines":

```
m=zeros((100,100))
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        m[i][j] = (int(i / 10) + int(j / 10)) % 2
```

Cheers.